# Confused on reversing an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I want to reverse an array that I input into a function.

But for some reason the console returns the first value of the array instead of taking the full array within the while loop so it can unshift the value at the end to the front then delete that same value.

```js
function littleWHEW(lemonade) {
  let i = lemonade.length - 1;
  while (i >= 0) {     
    lemonade.unshift(lemonade[i])
    lemonade.pop(lemonade[i])
    i = i - 1
  }
  return lemonade
}

console.info(littleWHEW([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Comment: Why are you passing an argument to [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)?

Comment: `lemonade.unshift(lemonade[i])` will duplicate `lemonade[i]` in the array. I suspect you think it will move it to the start but this is not the case

Comment: I'm thoroughly confused.  At first I thought you were trying to switch characters at the first and last position of the array, but you'd have to iterate over half the array and it would require more than `unshift` and `pop`

Comment: Ok, so why are you starting at the second-last element? You set `i` to `length - 1` but then the first thing you do in the loop is decrement `i`. That's not your only issue but it's the first thing I'd address

Comment: @Phil I'm kinda doing it in a roundabout what I try to get the loop to do is duplicate the last element and place it at the start. Then delete the element at the end of the array the it just duplicated.


let apples = [1,2,3,4,5]
apples
apples.unshift(apples[apples.length - 1])
(6) [5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
apples.pop(apples.length - 1)
5
apples
(5) [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: That is a really convoluted way to do what you want to do. Have you looked at `Array.reduce`? edit: actually `Array.reduceRight` would be perfect here.

Comment: @Phil ah sorry I was just testing to make sure the loop was working I fixed it now but it still only logs the first element of the array.

Comment: @SepZ that is illogical, when you finish iterating, you'll end up with what you started (e.g., `[1,2,3,4,5]`)

Comment: Why are you using such complicated approach to reverse array when you can do the same in more easy way? Why don't you use array.reverse() : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Comment: @VicJordan Its a exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked for explanation, let's take a deep investigation. Before we do, please take a look at 
`unshift` and `pop`

Firstly `i = 4`. Here're what happens in one loop:

1. `[1,2,3,4,5]` is the original array. `lemonade.unshift(lemonade[i])` adds one element to the first position of `lemonade`. At this point `i = 4` so `lemonade[4] = 5`, we have `[5,1,2,3,4,5]` (notice the bold).
2. Now you `pop` the last one out. `[5,1,2,3,4,5]` becomes `[5,1,2,3,4]`.
3. You decrease `i`.

Now `i = 3`, And here're what happens in second loop:

1. `[5,1,2,3,4]` is the original array. `lemonade.unshift(lemonade[i])` adds one element to the first position of `lemonade`. At this point `i = 3` so `lemonade[3] = 3`, we have `[3,5,1,2,3,4]` (notice the bold).
2. Now you `pop` the last one out. `[3,5,1,2,3,4]` becomes `[3,5,1,2,3]`.
3. You decrease `i`.

After one loop, your `i` does not point to the last element as expected, and makes things wrong (as second loop does).

Answer (score 1):

Just use the

```
reverse()
```

method:

```
function littleWHEW(lemonade) {
   return lemonade.reverse();
}
```

You should not add a parameter to the pop() method, by the way.

Comment: At least, can you explain what problems the OP is facing on?

Comment: Why, exactly should they use for loops...? They are iterating backwards *and* mutating the array. A for loop is not something you should use in this situation because you don't have a stable termination condition which is what a for loop is for.

Comment: can you explain why the function wrapper is necessary?

Comment: @vol7ron It's not. I included the function to not break the rest of OP's code if it references that function, or if he wants to do more in the function than just reversing the array.